# Storing and Retrieving Data in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I need your help,

For starters, I am getting an error with setting up my array like the below. What would be the proper way method do so and then retrieve its data like the following?

```
var office_a = {    
    name: [{
        name: "Alpha Branch", mailstop: "AB"
    }],    
    divisions: [{
        division1: "Division 1 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV1",
        division2: "Division 2 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV2",
        division3: "Division 3 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV3"
    }]    
};

function test() {    
    alert(office_a[name].name); // -> "Alpha Branch"    
    alert(office_a[name].mailstop); // -> "B1"    
    alert(office_a[divisions][division1.name]); // -> "Division 1 Office Name"    
    alert(office_a[divisions][division1.mailstop]); // -> "DIV1"
}

test();
```

Comment: first of all, you need to write: `var office_a = {...}` missing the `=` and `;` operator. Then you need to write `,` after each of your divisions. Syntax errors... Did I mention `;` after each alert?

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of accessing JavaScript objects. `office_a[name]` refers to **the property whose name is held in the variable `name`**. To refer to the property `name` itself, you need either `office_a.name`, or `office_a['name']`. This would be covered in any basic JS tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these (basically you need to account for array indexes inside the associative array). check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xv8e7sm/)

```
 var office_a = {    
    name: [{
        name: "Alpha Branch", mailstop: "AB"
    }],    
    divisions: [{
        division1: "Division 1 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV1",
        division2: "Division 2 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV2",
        division3: "Division 3 Office Name", mailstop: "DIV3"
    }]    
};
function test() {
console.log(office_a.name[0].name);
console.log(office_a.name[0].mailstop);
console.log(office_a.divisions[0].division1);
console.log(office_a.divisions[0].mailstop);
}
test();
```

Comment: How could this work if the variable `name` is not defined? How could it be the accepted answer if it doesn't work? By the way, in JS we do not call them "associative arrays".

Comment: @torazaburo made changes to the code, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @torazaburo I thought the exact same thing, but thankfully there is such a thing as the Edit button

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might expand on this subject. If you do the following:

```
console.log(office_a);
```

You will be able to see the following result on your web inspector (I am using Chrome). I will only type here the *relevant information* to achieve what you intend to achieve.

```
Object {name: Array[1], divisions: Array[1]}
    divisions: Array[1]
        0: Object
            division1: "Division 1 Office Name"
            division2: "Division 2 Office Name"
            division3: "Division 3 Office Name"
            mailstop: "DIV3"
    name: Array[1]
        0: Object
            mailstop: "AB"
            name: "Alpha Branch"
```

By looking at this you can get a very clear picture of how the browser interprets your object. Which first leads to using the **[JavaScript Literal Notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx)** in order to access its contents like via the `objectName.propertyName`:

```
console.log(office_a.name);
console.log(office_a.divisions);
```

This will produce the arrays seen above:

```
divisions
    0: Object
        division1: "Division 1 Office Name"
        division2: "Division 2 Office Name"
        division3: "Division 3 Office Name"
        mailstop: "DIV3"
name
    0: Object
        mailstop: "AB"
        name: "Alpha Branch"
```

From here you can access each individual object's contents, which in your case is an array which contains an object.

```
console.log(office_a.name[0]);
console.log(office_a.divisions[0]);
```

As I showed you already, accessing the specific contents of an object is as simple as using the desired property within that object. In your case, you want to see  all the contents so do the following:

```
console.log(office_a.name[0].name); // Alpha Branch
console.log(office_a.name[0].mailstop); // B1
console.log(office_a.divisions[0].division1); // Division 1 Office Name
console.log(office_a.divisions[0].mailstop); // DIV1
```

## TL;DR

Which leads to the following result (note I modified the `test()` function):

```js
var office_a = {
  name: [{
    name: "Alpha Branch",
    mailstop: "AB"
  }],
  divisions: [{
    division1: "Division 1 Office Name",
    mailstop: "DIV1",
    division2: "Division 2 Office Name",
    mailstop: "DIV2",
    division3: "Division 3 Office Name",
    mailstop: "DIV3"
  }]
};

function test(myObject) {
  alert(myObject.name[0].name); // Alpha Branch
  alert(myObject.name[0].mailstop); // B1
  alert(myObject.divisions[0].division1); // Division 1 Office Name
  alert(myObject.divisions[0].mailstop); // DIV1
}

test(office_a);
```